# DynamoDB conditional expression syntax

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to figure out how to make a conditional delete of an item. Assume a table with the attributes `(account, system, secret)`.  Let's say that I have the following code:

```
String mySecret = ...
final Map<String, AttributeValue> key = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
key.put("account", AttributeValue.builder()
    .s(account).build());
key.put("system", AttributeValue.builder()
    .s(system).build());

DeleteItemRequest request = DeleteItemRequest.builder()
    .tableName(DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME)
    .key(key)
    .build();
```

I'd like the `DeleteItemRequest` to succeed only if the value of `mySecret` matches the value of the attribute `secret` of the row to be deleted. How do I specify this in the `DeleteItemRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

Your request arguments should look something like this (in pseudocode):

```
{
    "TableName": "YOUR_TABLE",
    "Key": {
        "PK": "PARTITION_KEY", 
         "SK": "SORT_KEY"
    },
    "ConditionExpression": "#secretKey = :secretValue",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {"#secretKey":"secret"},
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":secretValue": {"S":"mySecret"}}
}
```

I believe you're missing a `ConditionExpression` from the `DeleteItemRequest`. It should look something like this.  I've not used Java to work with DDB, so there's probably a better way of doing this, but...

```
        Map<String, String> expressionAttributeNames = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        expressionAttributeNames.put("#secretKey", "mySecret");

        Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>(); 
        expressionAttributeValues.put(":secretValue", new AttributeValue("secret"));

        String conditionExpression = "#secretKey = :secretValue";
        deleteItemRequest.setConditionExpression(conditionExpression);
        deleteItemRequest.setExpressionAttributeNames(getExpressionAttributeNames());
        deleteItemRequest.setExpressionAttributeValues(getExpressionAttributeValues());
```

Oh, and keep in mind that `system` is a reserved word in DDB.